# Is there any way to show video in a web part on WSS 3.0?

Tags: web-part, wss-3.0, video

Is there any ready to use webpart that can be imported to a WSS 3.0 site, in order to view video embedded on website, with no extra coding or server changes?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your video hosted on some videosite (youtube, vimeo) you can just use the embed-code in a Content Editor Webpart.

**Pro**

- smaller content DB
- works on (almost) every browser
- faster (i'm not sure, it is just a feeling I have, using videos in SharePoint)

**Con**

- Video is not easy replaceable/editable
- Video is (semi)public
- Internet-connection needed.

Comment: and if its hosted on the same site

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2007/WSS3 does not come with the ability to stream videos.  In fact, it is particularly horrible at it even with BLOB caching enabled.  I would *STRONGLY* recommend hosting your videos elsewhere, like youtube, and then putting the EMBED code into your pages using the Content Editor Web Part.

However, if that is not an option and you must keep the videos in SharePoint, then look into incorporating one of the free video players out on the web.  One of the more common ones is [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/setup/index.html).

You will still have to add Javascript files to your site as well as create the actualy javascript needed to play the video.  that script would go in the Content Editor Web Part.

I would also recommend that you [enable BLOB caching](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-disk-based-cache-settings-HA010176284.aspx).  It won't solve all of the stuttering and lag issues you will see when playing videos from SharePoint, but it does ease them a bit.  Make sure you include the file extension of the videos you are streaming (i.e. flv, wmv) in the list of extensions to be included in the BLOBCache.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  http://svp.codeplex.com/. This is for Sharepoint and hope it works for WSS too.

Comment: can it be imported or i need to deploy from server, no documentation there

Comment: The download is a WSP. Thus you will need us stsadm.exe on the server to import the solution into your SharePoint Farm.

Comment: isn't there any other ready webpart, that can be imported to a specific site, or any other solution can be done from sharepoint designer ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/available-for-download-sharepoint-flash-media-library-template.aspx) is a document library template that might be useful for you.  It's designed to work with Flash videos uploaded to Sharepoint, but it can work with any video really.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the SharePoint Video Player available on the codeplex http://svp.codeplex.com/ and yes it works on WSS 3.0 site. It is a free open source project.